# How to blur points in 3d matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, blurry

Is it possible to blur some data points in matplotlib 3d, based on how long it is from the view point. I know as it is it will just opaque the points.

I'm looking for something similar to this;

http://vimeo.com/15669684

Answer (score 0):

You can blur using one of the colormaps from `matplotlib.cm`.

In the toy example below it is done a linear interpolation of the `z` coordinate which defines the color of each marker. The limits that tell the `z` values on the foreground and background are given by `zbf` and `zbb`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

n = 10
frames = 100
x = np.random.random(n)
y = np.random.random(n)
z = np.random.random(n)

zbb = 0. # z_blur_back
zbf = 1. # z_blur_fore

ax = plt.subplot(111)
fig = plt.gcf()

def animate(i):
    global x, y, z
    x += 0.01*(-0.5 + np.random.random(n))
    y += 0.01*(-0.5 + np.random.random(n))
    z += 0.05*(-0.5 + np.random.random(n))

    cmnum = (z-zbf)/(zbb-zbf)
    colors = cm.gray(cmnum) # use hot, ocean, rainbow etc...

    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.clear()
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=200., color=colors)
    ax.set_xlim(-0.1,1.1)
    ax.set_ylim(-0.1,1.1)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=xrange(frames))
ani.save('test.mp4', fps=20)
```

Comment: What version of matplotlib is required? Because when running the code locally with mpl version 1.1.1rc (ubuntu 12.04) it seems only to change the opacity of the points.

Comment: They should also randomly shake a little bit... I am using matplotlib 1.3.0...